# Unable to recreate a socket from file descriptor in Python

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I'm trying to recreate a socket in python from a file descriptor, but for some reason I keep getting an error

`OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`

I want to make sure it works in a console before writing the full script.

Here's console window 1:

```
>>> import socket
>>> wsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> wsock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
>>> wsock.listen()
>>> wsock.fileno()
580
```

And here's console window 2:

```
>>> import socket
>>> new_skt = socket.fromfd(580, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

What am I doing wrong?
And is there a difference when doing the same for Linux?

Comment: Both windows are the same process, right?

Comment: No, different processes.

Comment: The file descriptor number is a per-process resource, not global for the system. There are ways to transfer a file descriptor between processes but it's more complicated. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to redirect a connection from one socket to another. I want another socket to fully take control of the connection received by the first socket.

Comment: Why can't the second process open the socket in the first place? I'm not saying it's impossible to do what you want (inheriting file descriptors from a parent process is standard on all OS; sending fds works, [at least on Linux with a C API](https://www.sobyte.net/post/2022-01/pass-fd-over-domain-socket/)). However, it's not the normal way of doing it. Unless you have very specific needs, I recommend picking a different approach

Comment: I don't have any specific needs, all I want is to pass connections to another existing socket.

Comment: Well, this isn't part of the normal socket networking workflow. I've already linked to Linux's extension for making it happen. Windows seems to do it via [`WSADuplicateSocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaduplicatesocketa). I don't think the standard python API exposes either option directly but I could be wrong. You might find extensions for this or you might need to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File descriptors are private to each process. In your second Python program you should simply call `socket.socket()` to get a socket, bind it to the appropriate address, then use it to connect to the socket listening for connections in the first program. Also, binding to port zero is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: I bound to port 0 purely for testing purposes so that I don't have to bother with finding a free port. Thank you for your answer, I now understand what is going on.

Comment: Binding to port zero is fine for a socket that will connect to another socket; i.e., client to server. But getting a random port on the server isn't particularly useful. You would have to write the port number that was assigned somewhere that the client can find it so it knows which address to connect to.